# Elementary OS - can't take properly a screenshot or record a desktop

Tags: linux, elementary-os

Yesterday I installed Elementary OS Linux distro and it seems that I have this weird issue when trying to take a screenshot or record a desktop. I only get black images or black videos. Funny thing is that I can see a cursor. But all background remains black. I tried by reinstalling FGLRX driver for my ATI graphics card. Didn't help. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: It could be a video driver bug. What exact model of graphics card do you have? 32-bit or 64-bit system? What driver version? Have you tried the open-source driver?

Comment: @Gilles ATI Radeon 4650. System is 32 bit. No, I didn't try open-source driver.

Comment: I had similar problem, try Shutter form the software center.

Comment: I am having the same problem... It's an important tool for me, I may have to go back to Ubuntu.